# Built-in support for converting column names into values?

Tags: pandas

Does pandas have any *built-in support* for converting from this

```
   Foo  Bar  Baz  color  texture
0  845  758  421    red   creamy
1  259  512  405    red  crunchy
2  784  304  477  green   creamy
3  584  909  505  green  crunchy
4  282  756  619   blue   creamy
5  251  910  983   blue  crunchy
```

to this

```
   brand  color  texture  votes
0    Foo    red   creamy    845
1    Foo    red  crunchy    259
2    Foo  green   creamy    784
3    Foo  green  crunchy    584
4    Foo   blue   creamy    282
5    Foo   blue  crunchy    251
6    Bar    red   creamy    758
7    Bar    red  crunchy    512
8    Bar  green   creamy    304
9    Bar  green  crunchy    909
10   Bar   blue   creamy    756
11   Bar   blue  crunchy    910
12   Baz    red   creamy    421
13   Baz    red  crunchy    405
14   Baz  green   creamy    477
15   Baz  green  crunchy    505
16   Baz   blue   creamy    619
17   Baz   blue  crunchy    983
```

?

In words: *some* of the column headers have been converted into the values of a new column `brand`, and the values that were originally under these columns have been placed in a new column `votes`.

(Of course, the *names* 'brand' and 'votes' of the new columns cannot be deduced from the original dataframe; they'd need to be provided as additional data on top of the original dataframe.  Also, one could imagine that additional information could be provided about the position of the new columns among the dataframe's columns.)

**NB:  I don't help with implementing this conversion from simpler primitives.  I am asking whether *pandas* already has a function that will do it, and if so, what is it.**

---

FWIW, here's some code to generate the starting dataframe shown above:

```
import pandas
import itertools
import random

color = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
texture = ['creamy', 'crunchy']
brand = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']

random.seed(0)
records = [tuple(random.randint(1, 10000) for _ in brand) + p
           for p in itertools.product(color, texture)]
columns = brand + ['color', 'texture']
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=columns)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
>>> pandas.melt(dataframe, id_vars=["color", "texture"], var_name="brand", 
                           value_name="votes")
    color  texture brand  votes
0     red   creamy   Foo   6312
1     red  crunchy   Foo   4243
2   green   creamy   Foo   6635
3   green  crunchy   Foo   5867
4    blue   creamy   Foo   8269
5    blue  crunchy   Foo   2290
6     red   creamy   Bar   6891
7     red  crunchy   Bar   8377
8   green   creamy   Bar   4970
9   green  crunchy   Bar   9559
10   blue   creamy   Bar   2282
11   blue  crunchy   Bar   1554
12    red   creamy   Baz    664
13    red  crunchy   Baz   7962
14  green   creamy   Baz   7809
15  green  crunchy   Baz   3579
16   blue   creamy   Baz   4618
17   blue  crunchy   Baz   4105
```

AFAIK if you want to end up with a particular order you have to handle that yourself.